# login with social sites from client side with angular js

Tags: angularjs, oauth-2.0

I'm using [satellizer](https://github.com/sahat/satellizer) for social login in angular. but in this document it's mentioned that i need to do server side code also. exactly lines bellow

"Additionally, authorization (obtaining user's information with their permission) and authentication (application sign-in) requires sever-side implementation. See provided examples implemented in multiple languages for your convenience. In other words, you cannot just launch your AngularJS application and expect everything to work. The only exception is when you **use OAuth 2.0 Implicit Grant (client-side) authorization** by setting responseType: 'token' in provider's configuration."

In this it's mentioned that if i use OAuth 2.0 Implicit Grant (client-side) authorization then i don't need server side coding.

can any one please explain me what it is. and how can i use that with [satellizer](https://github.com/sahat/satellizer)?

Answer (score 0):

1. Create app_id,secret_key for facebook and for twitter create some consumer_key and customer_key
2. **npm install angular-social-login** Need to install this pakeage.
3. Follow the steps from here, given below link.
   https://github.com/Paldom/angular-social-login

Thanks
kunvar

Comment: but it will only work for facebook and google, i have to integrate facebook, twitter, google, linkedin,instagram